# Options to detect an ellipse in an image with overlapping an existing ellipse

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, ellipse

I want to recognize a specific shape in an image(in this case an ellipse) which i am given the shape with coordinates in either cartesian or polar coordinates, or an exact image of the shape. I am currently working with an image that i want to match in my picture.

I am relatively new to Python and i am currently learning with this project, this is was i had written by myself. Now i am trying to figure out how to identify the correct solution variant.

This is for an automated handling system of transparent objects, which should detect the object, overlay an image of the existing shape and then calculate the middle.

I tried some kind of a Canny and then work with findContours, this gave me unpleasant results because of much noise and other polygons in the picture.

I tried it with the ORB Method but this also gave not the results i was hoping for.

I tried it after that with a blob detector, no good results..

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 18, 18

    #Read Image for matching in GRAY
match = cv2.imread('/home/robin/Bilder/match3.png', 0)
    #Read Image to match in GRAY
orig = cv2.imread('/home/robin/Bilder/IMG_2848.JPG', 0) #Image for Searching

thresh2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(match, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, 
                    cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 7, 5)
resized = imutils.resize(orig, width=1000)
ratio = resized.shape[0] / float(resized.shape[0])

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(resized, (5, 5), 0)

bilat = cv2.bilateralFilter(blur, 10, 5, 1)

deno = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(bilat,None,18,5,10)

thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(deno, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, 
                    cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 7, 5)

plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(thresh, cmap = 'gray')
```

@HansHirse excuse me, i totally forgot to add the pictures!!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VPEW.jpg]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHODZ.jpg]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWYRI.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob98O.jpg]

I am trying to detect in an camera snapshot (Pic1) a ellipse from where i have the shape in form of the minor and major axis (here 70mm and 60mm). Basically i want to feed the programm a form (circle, ellipse, etc..) and it should mark this exact form in the original picture (with rotation and translation).

Comment: Could you please provide some example images, current outputs, and expected output(s)? That'd help other people to help you.

Comment: This isn't really a coding question, but it looks like you want a [Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform), possibly [this one](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html)

Comment: I wasnt sure about the question parameter, since i have to implement a desired function into my code, hence this sounded like a coding question. But i will give it a shot with the Hough transformation. Thanks in advance! Right now i am trying the HuMoments. If there are other ideas which i could possibly use, i am open to it and will post results.